# How do I put a variable in a range?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I copy and paste certain cells from Sheet2 to Sheet1 and have them keep the same properties such as colored text and background color? What I'm trying to do is find the same Serial Number in column F from both worksheets (Worksheet1 being the new one without any comments and Worksheet2 being the old one with comments), then making sure it's the right item by matching it's Assembly Number in column E (because there's many duplicate serial numbers with different assembly numbers), and lastly, copy the comments in columns R,S,T from Worksheet2 to Worksheet1. This seems to work but it only copies the text, not the certain words that are colored and the background color. This is what I have currently. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim ii As Integer

i = 2
ii = 2

For i = 2 To a
    For ii = 2 To a            

        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ii, 6) Then
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ii, 5) Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 18) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ii, 18)
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 19) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ii, 19)
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 20) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ii, 20)
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 21) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ii, 21)
            End If
        End If
    Next ii
Next i
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to say that I've tried to put in a Range such as Range("R"i,"T"i) inside the 2nd If statement so I could utilize the integer "i" in it making it the current row, but then it wont take it. What am I doing wrong? Or is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the four lines use this one instead:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ii, 18),Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ii, 21)).copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 18),Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 21))
```

or you could put them in a `With` block:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    .Range(.Cells(ii,18),.cells(ii,21)).copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 18),Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 21))
End With
```

Or to make it even shorter; Declare the worksheets as variables:

```
Dim ows as worksheet
Dim tws as worksheet

Set ows = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set tws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ows
    .Range(.Cells(ii,18),.cells(ii,21)).copy tws.Range(tws.Cells(i, 18),tws.Cells(i, 21))
End With
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm using the first line of code you provide. I just don't understand where's the code to paste it? It works perfectly though.

Comment: @AdministrativeAssistantMike With the `.Copy` function, the destination is an optional criteria.  So the paste part is everything after the `.Copy`